# Unset part of environmental variable PATH in batch script

Tags: windows, unix, batch-file, environment-variables

I am currently appending an environmental variable for PATH with this command:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;c:\Program Files\UnixUtils" /M
```

I would like to know how I would remove that from the PATH var while keeping the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set PATH=%PATH:c:\Program Files\UnixUtils=%
setx PATH "%PATH%" /M
```

does this work? the **:** symbol should not cause problems here...

Check also [REPLVAR.BAT here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5492)